# Image breaking rounded border in safari

Tags: html, css, image, rounded-corners

I've got some issues with rounded corners and images in safari. It works great in chrome though. Please take a look at this jsfiddle, explaining my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/2cTPw/1/

Why is this happening? What am I missing? I've tried searching for answers but all I can find is people having similar issues but nothing that solves my problem. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the border is not accounted for in safari. Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2cTPw/4/

Comment: Not nice at all markup-wise but it worked like a charm! :) I think this may be the only way to solve this problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in Safari.  The way to work around it is to set the image into the background of your div:

```
<div id="box" style="background-image:url(http://www.omnidev.se/images/uploads/omnidev_media.png)" />
</div>
```

See this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/qHG7z/

Comment: Thats a good solution but since I use javascript to resize and position the images after load this approach would be really complicated. But thanks!